# Tracking non-idle time spent on active tab in Google Chrome for a given domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension, time-tracking

I've never done any Chrome extension development for, but I'd like to monitor how long a certain tab is active showing a page originating from a given domain.

Where should I start? And perhaps there is already an extension tool for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found the [Time Tracker extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mokmnbikneoaenmckfmgjgjimphfojkd).